# Browser swt on Raspberry Pi can't play audio when click a video on youtube

Tags: raspbian, java

Firstly, I am sorry about my bad english.
I am doing a web browser on Raspberry Pi. 
I use Java SWT Browser Widget and this browser work fine, but it don't play audio when i click a video on youtube.
I use Raspbean OS.
Can someone give me the solution?
Thanks you : ))

Comment: are you able to play any embedded audio? .... maybe the browser does not have the necessary permissions to play audio   ..... check here .... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio .... i do not know if it will play on a browser widget that you are using

Comment: here is some info that may help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440484/embed-a-youtube-video-to-jframe ...... by the way, your english is just fine